# Processing 3.5.3 software is not starting in Windows 10

Tags: processing

I downloaded processing 3.5.3 and extracted it to a folder ... And then when I click on application name processing in that folder, it just shows the logo of software for 3-4 seconds and then disappears i.e it doesn't start the main screen of the software..

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Processing and reinstalling? Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: also, have you tried opening a command prompt, going to that folder, and typing "processing.exe" to see if that generates any error?

Answer (score 0):

disable anti virus
open it as administrator
if it doesn't work download it again or reinstall